# Intel XDK template app and iFrames not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, intel-xdk

I'm trying to open iFrames within the different tabs of the app. The problem that is happening is that if I place an iFrame in the first tab(page of app), I cannot access any of the tabs below it. But if there is text such as `<p>Bla Bla</p>` it works fine. If I put the iFrame in the last tab, all of the above work fine. I'm new to html5 cross platform apps, and very new to intel XDK. Thanks in advance.

CODE:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Grid View App template</title>
<!--
    This template can be used for photo app with grid view that will open detail view, for applications like Photo App or Instagram app.
-->  
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0;" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="appframework/af.ui.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="appframework/icons.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="appframework/appframework.ui.min.js"></script>

    <!-- phantom library, needed for XDK "legacy" container api calls -->
    <script src="intelxdk.js"></script>
    <!-- phantom library, needed for Cordova api calls -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>
    <!-- phantom library, needed for XDK "legacy" container CORS -->
    <script src="xhr.js"></script>

    <script>
        var onDeviceReady=function(){                             // called when Cordova is ready
           if( window.Cordova && navigator.splashscreen ) {     // Cordova API detected
               $.ui.launch(); 
               navigator.splashscreen.hide() ;                 // hide splash screen
            }
        } ;
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false) ;
    </script>

    <script>   
        $.ui.autoLaunch = false; 
        $.ui.backButtonText = "Back";

        $(document).ready(function(){
            $.ui.launch();
        });
    </script>
    <style>
/* CSS responsive square grid */        
.grid-photo {margin:3px -7px;} 
.grid-photo:after {content:'';display:block;clear:both;}        
.grid-photo li {position: relative; display:block; float:left; width: 10%; padding-bottom: 10%;}
.grid-photo .grid-photo-box {position: absolute;left: 3px;right: 3px;top: 3px;bottom: 3px; background-color: rgba(128,128,128,0.2);} 
.grid-photo img {width:100%;height:100%}
@media only screen and (max-width : 1024px) {
    .grid-photo li {width: 12.5%; padding-bottom: 12.5%;}        
}        
@media only screen and (max-width : 768px) {
    .grid-photo li {width: 16.6%; padding-bottom: 16.6%;}        
}        
@media only screen and (max-width : 480px) {
    .grid-photo li {width: 25%; padding-bottom: 25%;}        
}
@media only screen and (max-width : 320px) {
    .grid-photo li {width: 33.3%; padding-bottom: 33.3%;}        
}   
    </style>    
</head>
<body> 
<div id="afui">
    <div id="content" style="">

    <!--Grid View Page-->
        <div class="panel" title="Title" id="gridview" selected="true">
            <header>
                <h1>Title</h1>
                <a href="#" class="button icon refresh" style="float:right"></a>
            </header>
            <div class="grid-photo">
                <li><div class="grid-photo-box"><a href="#item1"><img src="" /></a></div></li>
                <li><div class="grid-photo-box"><a href="#item2"><img src="" /></a></div></li>
                <li><div class="grid-photo-box"><a href="#item3"><img src="" /></a></div></li>
                <li><div class="grid-photo-box"><a href="#item4"><img src="" /></a></div></li>
                <li><div class="grid-photo-box"><a href="#item5"><img src="" /></a></div></li>
                <li><div class="grid-photo-box"><a href="#item6"><img src="" /></a></div></li>
                <li><div class="grid-photo-box"><a href="#item7"><img src="" /></a></div></li>
                <li><div class="grid-photo-box"><a href="#item8"><img src="" /></a></div></li>
                <li><div class="grid-photo-box"><a href="#item9"><img src="" /></a></div></li>
                <li><div class="grid-photo-box"><a href="#item10"><img src="" /></a></div></li>
                <li><div class="grid-photo-box"><a href="#item11"><img src="" /></a></div></li>
                <li><div class="grid-photo-box"><a href="#item12"><img src="" /></a></div></li>
                <li><div class="grid-photo-box"><a href="#item13"><img src="" /></a></div></li>
                <li><div class="grid-photo-box"><a href="#item14"><img src="" /></a></div></li>
                <li><div class="grid-photo-box"><a href="#item15"><img src="" /></a></div></li>
                <li><div class="grid-photo-box"><a href="#item16"><img src="" /></a></div></li>
                <li><div class="grid-photo-box"><a href="#item17"><img src="" /></a></div></li>
                <li><div class="grid-photo-box"><a href="#item18"><img src="" /></a></div></li>
                <li><div class="grid-photo-box"><a href="#item19"><img src="" /></a></div></li>
                <li><div class="grid-photo-box"><a href="#item20"><img src="" /></a></div></li>
                <li><div class="grid-photo-box"><a href="#item21"><img src="" /></a></div></li>
                <li><div class="grid-photo-box"><a href="#item22"><img src="" /></a></div></li>
                <li><div class="grid-photo-box"><a href="#item23"><img src="" /></a></div></li>
                <li><div class="grid-photo-box"><a href="#item24"><img src="" /></a></div></li>
            </div>
            <a id="more" class="button block">Load More</a>
        </div>

    <!--Detail View Pages for each grid items-->
        <div class="panel" title="Item 1" id="item1">
            <p><iframe width="100%" height="600px" frameborder="0" src="http://www.google.com" /></p>
        </div>

        <div class="panel" title="Item 2" id="item2">
            <p>This is detail view for Item 2</p>
        </div>

        <div class="panel" title="Item 3" id="item3">
            <p>This is detail view for Item 3</p>
        </div>

        <div class="panel" title="Item 4" id="item4">
            <p>This is detail view for Item 4</p>
        </div>

        <div class="panel" title="Item 5" id="item5">
            <p>This is detail view for Item 5</p>
        </div>

        <div class="panel" title="Item 6" id="item6">
            <p>This is detail view for Item 6</p>
        </div>

        <div class="panel" title="Item 7" id="item7">
            <p>This is detail view for Item 7</p>
        </div>

        <div class="panel" title="Item 8" id="item8">
            <p>This is detail view for Item 8</p>
        </div>

        <div class="panel" title="Item 9" id="item9">
            <p>This is detail view for Item 9</p>
        </div>

        <div class="panel" title="Item 10" id="item10">
            <p>This is detail view for Item 10</p>
        </div>

        <div class="panel" title="Item 11" id="item11">
            <p>This is detail view for Item 11</p>
        </div>

        <div class="panel" title="Item 12" id="item12">
            <p>This is detail view for Item 12</p>
        </div>

        <div class="panel" title="Item 13" id="item13">
            <p>This is detail view for Item 13</p>
        </div>

        <div class="panel" title="Item 14" id="item14">
            <p>This is detail view for Item 14</p>
        </div>

        <div class="panel" title="Item 15" id="item15">
            <p>This is detail view for Item 15</p>
        </div>

        <div class="panel" title="Item 16" id="item16">
            <p>This is detail view for Item 16</p>
        </div>

        <div class="panel" title="Item 17" id="item17">
            <p>This is detail view for Item 17</p>
        </div>

        <div class="panel" title="Item 18" id="item18">
            <p>This is detail view for Item 18</p>
        </div>

        <div class="panel" title="Item 19" id="item19">
            <p>This is detail view for Item 19</p>
        </div>

        <div class="panel" title="Item 20" id="item20">
            <p>This is detail view for Item 20</p>
        </div>

        <div class="panel" title="Item 21" id="item21">
            <p>This is detail view for Item 11</p>
        </div>

        <div class="panel" title="Item 22" id="item22">
            <p>This is detail view for Item 12</p>
        </div>

        <div class="panel" title="Item 23" id="item23">
            <p>This is detail view for Item 13</p>
        </div>

        <div class="panel" title="Item 24" id="item24">
            <p>This is detail view for Item 14</p>
        </div>        

    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is related to simple HTML syntax.
Just close the iframe tag and it will work.

I.E.:

```
<iframe width="100%" height="600px" frameborder="0" src="http://www.google.com"></iframe>
```

The previous behavior is due to missing closure tag (all the rest of your code was "trapped" inside the previously opened IFRAME).